# How to print files with PDF.js without header & footer on IE11?

Tags: pdf, printing, pdf-generation, pdf.js

I've searched in many posts in https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/ and none seems to solve the issue.

When printing the PDF files from PDF.js viewer Under IE11, the printed page contains pagination in the header and a link + date in the footer.

I know i can disable them from IE printing settings, but i Don't imagine asking thousands of clients to do so …
Is there a workaround to get rid of the header & footer ?

Comment: did you find it?

Comment: not really, we had to change the plugin and use acrobat reader instead of pdf.js